# how to do a update statement with a subquery?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, subquery

I am trying to update a table using the information that exist from another table. the table that I want to update is called YVDtemp and the second table I am getting the information from is called yvs_textsMain. I also use a 3rd table to match any records that I dont have and this table is called YVD. Here is my update statement.

```
 update Yvdtemp
 set
 NAME  = yvd_textsmain.[name] 
 SPIC = yvd_textsmain.[rname]
 EFFECT = yvd_textsmain.[desc] 
 where exists (
 select yvd_textsMain.[name], yvd_textsMain.[rname], yvd_textsMain.[desc] 
 from YVD_textsMain
 left outer join YVD 
 on (YVD_textsMain.[rname] = yvd.[spic])
 where yvd.[spic] is null);
```

It seems that this statement is not working. It gives me an error "near 'spic': syntax error
but, when i use use the select statement apart from the update statement the select statement works and I get all the information that is not in YVD table and that information I want to pass it into YVDTemp table.

I am using SQLite.

Comment: you are missing comma between columns it should be `NAME = yvd_textsmain.[name] , SPIC = yvd_textsmain.[rname],EFFECT = yvd_textsmain.[desc] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no matching condition between `Yvdtemp` and `yvd_textsmain` how will you map the rows in update statement. 
Based on the requirement it looks like you are looking out for an `Insert` command which can be written as:

```
INSERT INTO Yvdtemp (NAME, SPIC, EFFECT) 
 Select yvd_textsMain.[name], yvd_textsMain.[rname], yvd_textsMain.[desc] 
 from YVD_textsMain
 left outer join YVD 
 on (YVD_textsMain.[rname] = yvd.[spic])
 where yvd.[spic] is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss the commas

```
NAME  = yvd_textsmain.[name],
SPIC = yvd_textsmain.[rname],
EFFECT = yvd_textsmain.[desc]
```